# "invalid source token" while deploying a function to fireabse

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

i got wired issued with firebase deployment using:

```
firebase deploy -P dev
```

the error is

```
✔  functions[testFunction(us-central1)] Successful update operation.
Invalid source token
```

looks like its happen to new functions that created

when i tried to deploy specific function using:

```
firebase -deploy -P dev --only functions:name
```

its working

when i run and deploy all functions and all my apps i am getting the above error with no information

also the logs from google cloud function is:

```
status: {
code: 9
message: "Invalid source token"
}
```

firebase tools version 11.0.0
node: 14.19.3

Comment: Could you please try to upgrade your firebase-tools to the latest version using `npm i firebase-tools@latest -g`

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB the issues is that i have node 14.9
and the maximum is firebase-tools is 11.0

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to atleast node 16 as there's an open issue regarding the "Invalid Source Token" on your current firebase-tools version. There's already a pull request regarding that issue and it will be fixed on the upcoming updates. Here's the [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4266) for reference.

Comment: thx
i got now 
HTTP Error: 429, Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Write requests' and limit 'Write requests per minute' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com

it could be related to the same issue?
sometimes it works and sometimes no

split the whole project to multiple project in the same repo and then run firebase deploy per project could assist?

Comment: Are you on Free Tier?

Comment: no, blaze plan, i dont see that im on the limit on gcloud

Comment: thx 
i have upgraded the ftools + node version and there is still issue with invalid source token

Comment: I would suggest contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) regarding with your issue.